# EJB @Timeout method is getting called multiple times during hot re deployment in weblogic server

Tags: java, timer, timeout, ejb

We have the following simple app: one @Singleton bean with @Timeout method and one servlet which starts timer. After first deploy we see that method is called once in 2 seconds - which is expected. Then after hot re-deploy we see that method is called twice within 2 seconds. After a few redeploys method is called multiple times during the same 2 seconds. Restarting the server doesn't help. See the code below:

```
import javax.ejb.*;

@Remote(TimerRemote.class)
@Singleton
public class TimerBean implements TimerRemote {
  @Resource
  private SessionContext context;

  public void startTimer() {
    context.getTimerService().createTimer(2000,2000,null);    
  }

  @Timeout
  public void timeoutCallback(javax.ejb.Timer timer) {
    System.out.println("timeoutCallback is called: " + timer);
  }
}
```

@Timeout method should be called after given interval time. Currently method is getting called multiple times within a second.

Answer (score 0):

The timer is persistent per default and is not cancelled at all.

Please refer to the official [Java EE6 Tutorial: Using the Timer Service](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html#bnboz).

Prefer using `@Schedule` and set `persistent=false` if you don't need the timer to be persistent. Or try a programmatic approach controlling the lifecycle of the timer on your own.